# Printing the position of the bigger letter in a list of characters

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql

I am having some logic thinking trouble with this task. 
So the task asks to return the position of the first bigger letter in a list of letters. 
For example:

```
             ABVD -> 3
             BCDG -> 4 
             CFDE -> 2
```

This tasks suggests to use lenght, ascii, and named block, function

So this is what I could do so far:

```
declare 
x varchar2(10) :='ABFD';
BEGIN 
FOR i in 1..length(x) LOOP
dbms_output.put_line(ASCII(SUBSTR(x, i, 1)));
END LOOP;
END;
```

My thought was to turn the letters to numbers : 65, 66, 70, 68. The pattern is x + 1 and since the number 70 is not equal 66 + 1, so the program will return the position of that number, which is 3. 
Unfortunately I don't know how turn this idea into code. Can you give me some hints/suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Why convert to numbers? Yes, 70 > 65, but so is 'F' > 'A'.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I didn't know that we can actually do that.

Answer (score 1):

In the problem statement you said "... use named block, function."

Your solution is an anonymous procedure. It is not named anywhere (which is why it is called "anonymous"). And it is not a function - it doesn't return anything.

I will let you study the documentation to understand the difference between function and procedure, and how to name a function or procedure. Below I will follow your lead and show how you can modify your code to make it into a workable anonymous procedure. (In the procedure I "print" the final value of `ind`; when you change this to a function, you should `return` that value, instead of printing it.)

In the code you posted, you are printing the letters in the input string, one by one. You are not even attempting to define or assign to an integer (the index of the first occurrence of the "highest" letter in the string). That should be done in the DECLARE block. Then we also need to store the highest letter found "so far" (for future comparisons).

The code might look like this:

```
declare 
x varchar2(10) :='ABFD';
ind number := 1;
max_letter char(1) := substr(x, 1, 1);
BEGIN 
FOR i in 2..length(x) LOOP
  if substr(x, i, 1) > max_letter
  then max_letter := substr(x, i, 1);
       ind := i;
  end if;
END LOOP;
dbms_output.put_line(ind);
END;
/
```

Note that letters can be compared to each other directly, there is no reason to convert them to numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Pure SQL using model clause

```
with t(str) as
(select 'ABVD' from dual
union all select 'BCDG' from dual
union all select 'CFDE' from dual)
select str, instr(str, max_chr) ind
from t
model
partition by (rownum rn)
dimension by (1 dummy)
measures (str, chr(1) max_chr)
rules
iterate (4e3) until (substr(str[1], iteration_number + 2, 1) is null)
(max_chr[1] = greatest(max_chr[1], substr(str[1], iteration_number + 1, 1)));

STR         IND
---- ----------
ABVD          3
BCDG          4
CFDE          2
```